# how can I use AND operator in IF statement in nginx?

Tags: if-statement, nginx, and-operator

I'm trying to cache the request based on the response header.
Right now my desire condition is if the response has both 2 headers client-device and client-location, then the response should be cached on nginx side

So I tried with this code

```
if ($http_client_device && $http_clocation) {
    set $cache_key "$request_uri$http_client_device$http_client_location";
}
proxy_cache_key $cache_key;
```

but nginx doesn't allow that
    nginx: [emerg] unexpected "&&" in condition in...

anyway to work around for this one?
thanks in advance

Answer (score 28):

After searching around the whole day, I reach a work around way, reference to this topic
http://rosslawley.co.uk/archive/old/2010/01/04/nginx-how-to-multiple-if-statements/

So in general my code will look like this:

```
    if ($http_client_device) {
        set $temp_cache 1;
    }
    if ($http_client_location) {
        set $temp_cache 1$temp_cache;
    }
    if ($temp_cache = 11) {
        set $cache_key ...; 
    }
```

but still wonder is there any cleaner way to do AND operator in nginx

Comment: Sometimes I feel NGINX is so stupid. I ended up with the same thing.

Answer (score 22):

### Method 1

Use `if` as less as possible.

- **Be careful**, Nginx change the context block when `if` matched ([more detail](https://www.nginx.com/resources/wiki/start/topics/depth/ifisevil/))
- To avoid `if` change the context block, using `map` is better

```bash
# if ($arg_a == "" && $arg_b == "")

http {
  # map need in http context
  map "$arg_a$arg_b" $is_empty {
    default 0;
    "" 1;
  }
  server {
    if ($is_empty) {
      # ...
    }
    # ...
  }
}
```

To check multiple match

```bash
# if ($arg_a == "apple" && $arg_b == "boy")

http {
    # map need in http context
    map $arg_a $match_a {
        default 0;
        apple 1;
    }
    map $arg_b $match_b {
        default 0;
        boy 1;
    }
    map "$match_a$match_b" $match {
        default 0;
        11 1;
    }

    server {
        if ($match) {
            # ...
        }
        # ...
    }
}
```

### Method 2

If you confirm your config works even `if` change the context block.

```bash
set $and 1;

if (<not condition>) {
    set $and 0;
}

if (<not condition>) {
    set $and 0;
}

if ($and) {
    # ...
}
```

For example:

```bash
if ($arg_a = 1 && $arg_b = 2) { ... }
```

can achieve with

```bash
set $ab 1

if ($arg_a != 1) {
    set $ab 0;
}

if ($arg_b != 2) {
    set $ab 0;
}

if ($ab) {
    # ...
}
```

> Ref: [Nginx `if`, `and`](https://steelywing.github.io/note/Note/Nginx/Variable/#operator-and)

For your case

```bash
set $set_cache_key 1;
if ($http_client_device = "") {
    set $set_cache_key 0;
}
if ($http_clocation = "") {
    set $set_cache_key 0;
}
if ($set_cache_key) {
    set $cache_key "$request_uri$http_client_device$http_client_location";
}
proxy_cache_key $cache_key;
```